# $\mathrm{Homeo}_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{R})$ is a perfect group

Tags: group-theory

I would like to show that $$\mathrm{Homeo}_{\Bbb Z} (\Bbb R)= \{ f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R \in \mathrm{Homeo}(\mathbb{R}) \mid \forall x, f(x+1)=f(x)+1 \}$$ is a perfect group (ie. equal to its derived subgroup). I already know that the group $\mathrm{Homeo}^+(\mathbb{S}^1)$ of increasing homeomorphisms of the circle is perfect.

If $\tilde{f}_1,\dots,\tilde{f}_r : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ lift $f_1, \dots, f_r : \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ respectively, then $w(\tilde{f}_1,\dots,\tilde{f}_r)$ lifts $w(f_1,\dots,f_r)$ for any word $w$. Therefore, because any element of $\mathrm{Homeo}_{\Bbb Z} (\Bbb R)$ is a lift of an element of $\mathrm{Homeo}^+(\mathbb{S}^1)$ and that two lifts disagree by a power of $T : x \mapsto x+1$, we deduce that any element of $\mathrm{Homeo}_{\Bbb Z}(\mathbb{R})$ can be written as a power of $T$ followed by a product of commutators.

To conclude, it is then sufficient to show that $T$ is a commutator in $\mathrm{Homeo}_{\Bbb Z}(\mathbb{R})$. Although it is easy in $\mathrm{Homeo}(\mathbb{R})$ (a translation is a commutator of two reflections), it seems to be more difficult in $\mathrm{Homeo}_{\Bbb Z}(\mathbb{R})$. Do you have an idea?

Comment: If you use the Euler class of the standard (genus $g$) surface group action on the circle, you see that the translation by $2g-2$ is a product of commutators of elements of $Homeo_Z(R)$. Thus, (using $g=2$), translation by 2 is in the commutator subgroup. Working a bit harder one constructs surface group actions (nondiscrete ones) with Euler class 1 too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never heard about what you are dealing with...

Comment: I think, Ghys has several papers which you would enjoiy reading, which discuss relation of the rotation number and the Euler class. I will dig out some references...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brief explanation, I will write more details later on, when I have time. Consider a closed oriented hyperbolic surface $S$ of genus $g\ge 2$. The hyperbolic structure on $S$ determines a properly discontinuous isometric action of the group $\Gamma=\pi_1(S)$ on the unit disk $D$ (Poincaré model of hyperbolic plane). In particular, we get an action of the surface group on the unit circle $S^1$ bounding $D$. Consider the associated $S^1$-bundle $\xi: E\to S$. The Euler number $e(\xi)$ of this bundle equals $\chi(S)$ (since this circle bundle is isomorphic to the unit tangent bundle of $S$). Let $a_1,b_2,\dots,a_g, b_g$ be the standard generators of $\Gamma$,
$$
\prod_i [a_i, b_i]=1. 
$$
Now, let's lift the action of $\Gamma$ from the circle to the real line. The obstruction to the lifting is precisely the Euler class of $\xi$ and one verifies that if $\tilde a_i, \tilde b_i$ are lifts of the generators of $\Gamma$ to homeomorphisms of ${\mathbb R}$ (it does not matter which lifts you take), then
$$
\prod_i [\tilde a_i, \tilde b_i] =\tau, \tau(x)=x+(2-2g), 
$$
translation of the real line. In particular, all even translations of the real line are in the commutator subgroup of $\mathrm{Homeo}_Z({\mathbb R})$.

Etienne Ghys has several very nice papers discussing Euler class of the group of homeomorphisms of the circle, which, I think, you are familiar with at least some of them, these papers probably contain explanations of the above interpretation of the Euler class.

One can also get isometric actions of $\Gamma$ on the hyperbolic plane (no longer properly discontinuous) for which the Euler number can take any integer value between $\chi(S)$ and $-\chi(S)$. (Ghys likely discusses these as well in one of his papers.)  Thus, by repeating the above argument, one shows that the entire group of integers lies in the commutator subgroup.

Comment: I come back to your answer, with a little more background, and the proof you sketch seems to be very nice! Do you have some precise references? (I searched on Ghys' webpage, but there are a lot of things.)